# Storing selected value from a combobox into database

Tags: php, html, mysql

im trying to create a form with a text input and a combobox loaded with values and data retrieved from a database. The idea is that when you submit the form, the value from the text field will be stored in one of the fields of the database. What i need to do is to store the selected value (numeric and extracted from other table of the db) of the combo box (not the displayed text in the combo), into the same table where the text field of the form will be stored.

The database structure consists on two tables named countries and appellations. Countries have one field named country_id and another named country_name (those two fields populate the combobox. The table Appellations have three fields named appellation_id (pk, nn, ai), country_id, and appellation_name. The appellation_name field must be filled with data submitted in the text field of the form, and country_id must be filled with the selected value of the combobox, which is equal to the country_id value of the countries table.
SO far i have been able to create the form and load all the countries in the combobox with db values.

the form code is

```
<form name="New Appellation" action="actions/register_appellation.php" method="POST"     onsubmit="return validate()">
Nombre denominacion de origen:
<input type="text" placeholder="Nombre DO" name="fappellation_name">
<br>
Pais denominacion de origen:
<?php
include_once 'includes/fast_conn.php';
mysqli_select_db($cn,$db_name) or die(mysql_error());
$sql = "SELECT country_name, country_id FROM countries";
$rs = mysqli_query($cn,$sql) or die(mysql_error());
echo "<select name='appellation_country'>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)){
echo "<option value='".$row["country_id"]."'>".$row["country_name"]."</option>";
}mysqli_free_result($rs);
echo "</select>";
?>
<input type="submit" value="Registrar">

</form>
```

and the php handling the POST register_appellation.php is:

```
<?php
include_once '../includes/fast_conn.php';
$fappellation_name=$_POST['fappellation_name'];
$fcountry_id=$_POST['country_id'];
$save="INSERT INTO $db_name($fcountry_id, $$fappellation_name)";
$result=mysqli_query($cn,$save);
if($result){
echo "<font size='+1' color='blue'> $fappellation_name, Successfully Registered.</font>";

}
else
{

echo "<font size='+1' color='red'>Registration Failed.</font>";

}
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You're mixing MySQL APIs with `mysql_error()` they do **not** mix. Using error reporting would have signaled that.

Comment: changed mysql_error() to mysqli_error($cn), but no changes. Still getting Notice: Undefined index: country_id in register_appellation.php on line 4

Comment: It's because your form doesn't have a named element called `country_id` to work with `$fcountry_id=$_POST['country_id'];`. The only element in there is `<input type="text" placeholder="Nombre DO" name="fappellation_name">` that's why you're getting that Undefined index warning.

Comment: Another thing `$save="INSERT INTO $db_name($fcountry_id, $$fappellation_name)";` there's two `$` signs for `$$fappellation_name` plus, you're not including `VALUES` and the columns. I.e.: `$save="INSERT INTO $db_name (column1,column2) VALUES ($fcountry_id, $fappellation_name)";`

Comment: Fred, can you please elaborate a little more on how to name an element called country_id in a combobox element in html. Thank you very much in advance, im really stuck here.

Comment: *"The database structure consists on two tables named countries and appellations."* - You're wanting to use two tables, which is what I don't quite understand. You're only selecting one table `countries` `SELECT country_name, country_id FROM countries` you will need to use some kind of `JOIN` for that and I'm not very good with those.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I believe he wants to store the completed applications in one table, but he wants to use the other table as an information repository which would contain information about all of the countries available.

Answer (score 0):

I've included the revised source below which should handle the issue.

I did a few things in the source. I believe it all should be documented fairly well. Here is a list of things I added:

1. The code is now updated to fully use MySQLi.
2. The MySQLi in both forms is OOP style (my preference for MySQLi).
3. There are error checks to see if things were successful and display errors accordingly.
4. `register_appellation.php` now checks to see if fields were filled in.
5. `register_appellation.php` now performs sanitation on query variables. (Helps prevents SQL injection attacks)
6. `register_appellation.php` now confirms that the country id it receives is valid by cross referencing with the `countries` table.

---

Here's the form code:

```
<form name="New Appellation" action="actions/register_appellation.php" method="POST"    onsubmit="return validate()">
Nombre denominacion de origen:
<input type="text" placeholder="Nombre DO" name="fappellation_name">
<br>
Pais denominacion de origen:
<?php
include_once 'includes/fast_conn.php';
$boolSelectionSuccessful = $cn->select_db($db_name);
if(!$boolSelectionSuccessful){
    $deathMessage = "<br><div>" .
        "Oh no! An error occurred on our end!<br>" .
        "Here's what we know:<hr>" .
        $cn->error .
        "<hr>" .
        "If this error continues to occur, please contact the website administrator." .
        "</div>";
    die($deathMessage);
}
$sql = "SELECT `country_name`, `country_id` FROM `countries`";
$rs = $cn->query($sql);
if($rs === FALSE){
    $deathMessage = "<br><div>" .
        "Oh no! An error occurred on our end!<br>" .
        "Here's what we know:<hr>" .
        $cn->error .
        "<hr>" .
        "If this error continues to occur, please contact the website administrator." .
        "</div>";
    die($deathMessage);
}
echo "<select name='appellation_country'>";
while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<option value='".$row["country_id"]."'>".$row["country_name"]."</option>";
}
$rs->close();
echo "</select>";
?>
<input type="submit" value="Registrar">
</form>
```

Here's register_appellation.php

```
<?php
include_once '../includes/fast_conn.php';

function checkField($fieldName){
    if(isset($_POST[$fieldName])){
        if(!empty($_POST[$fieldName])){
            /* The request has the fieldName submitted && the fieldName was not left empty */
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

$checkArray = array(checkField('fappellation_name'), checkField('appellation_country'));
if(in_array(false, $checkArray) || !is_numeric($_POST['appellation_country'])){
    /* the check assumes that 'appellation_country' (country id) should be numeric */
    die("<font size='+1' color='red'>Registration Failed. Please fill in all forms.</font>");
}

$boolSelectionSuccessful = $cn->select_db($db_name);
if(!$boolSelectionSuccessful){
    $deathMessage = "<br><div>" .
        "Oh no! An error occurred on our end!<br>" .
        "Here's what we know:<hr>" .
        $cn->error .
        "<hr>" .
        "If this error continues to occur, please contact the website administrator." .
        "</div>";
    die($deathMessage);
}
$sql = "SELECT `country_name`, `country_id` FROM `countries`";
$rs = $cn->query($sql);
if($rs === FALSE){
    $deathMessage = "<br><div>" .
        "Oh no! An error occurred on our end!<br>" .
        "Here's what we know:<hr>" .
        $cn->error .
        "<hr>" .
        "If this error continues to occur, please contact the website administrator." .
        "</div>";
    die($deathMessage);
}

$countryIdValid = False;
$countryName = "";
/* $countryName is unused, by the current code, but it will still be set in the while loop.
   If you want to store the country name in the `appeallations` table, this variable
   could simply be added to the insert statement. */

while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()){
    if($row['country_id'] == $_POST['appellation_country']){
        $countryIdValid = true;
        $countryName = $row['country_name'];
        break;
    }
    /* else - continue looping to check the next country_id */
}

$rs->close();

/* now that the loop has been exited, we'll make sure the country_id was verified */
if(!$countryIdValid){
    die("<font size='+1' color='red'>Registration Failed. Unknown country.</font>");
}

$fappellation_name= $cn->real_escape_string($_POST['fappellation_name']);
$fcountry_id = $cn->real_escape_string($_POST['appellation_country']);
$save="INSERT INTO `appellations` (`country_id`, `appellation_name`) VALUES ('$fcountry_id', '$fappellation_name')";
$result = $cn->query($save);
if($result !== FALSE){
    echo "<font size='+1' color='blue'> " . $_POST['fappellation_name'] . ", Successfully Registered.</font>";
}else{
    $deathMessage = "<br><div>" .
        "Oh no! An error occurred on our end!<br>" .
        "Here's what we know:<hr>" .
        $cn->error .
        "<hr>" .
        "If this error continues to occur, please contact the website administrator." .
        "</div>";
    die($deathMessage);
}
?>
```

---

If I have missed anything, please feel free to edit and update my answer. I have not ran the code, so there may be syntax or logic errors which I did not notice.

Hope this helps,

Spencer

Comment: Thank you Spencer, worked flawlessly. A couple if single quotes missing in the insert mysql statement. Worked perfect THANK YOU again !!

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I'll add those in. Anyway, no problem. I also recommend adding in a check when you first open the connection. This can be done as `if($cn->connect_error){ die($cn->connect_errno . '<br>' . $cn->connect_error); /* or whatever other message you want to die with. */ }`

Comment: Just updated that error in the MySQLi statement and changed the undefined country_id error from `Unknown country code.` to `Unknown country.`  If this works, please consider accepting the answer and, if you're content with it, upvoting it. If the answer is unaccepted, it stays open as an unanswered question.